# Relations on the set of Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I need a relation on $\Bbb R$; that is neither reflexive, nor symmetric, nor transitive.

I thought of $a$ ~ $b$ where $a=b^2+1$ (mostly)

Not reflexive because: $a^2 \neq a^2 + 1$ (mostly)

Not symmetric because:  if  $a=b^2+1$ then $b\neq a^2+1$ (mostly)

Not Transitive because: if $a=b^2+1$ and $b=c^2+1$ then $a\neq c^2+1$ (mostly)

I need a relation on $\Bbb R$; that is transitive and reflexive, not symmetric.

this one I'm stuck on and don't know where to start really.

Comment: You could do easyer: $R=\{\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,2\rangle\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ is not reflexive, not symmetric and not transitive.

Comment: but isnt that in R2 and not on R?

Comment: A relation *on* $\mathbb R$ is by definition a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. In your own example $R=\{\langle b^2+1,b\rangle\mid b\in\mathbb R\}\subset\mathbb R^2$

Comment: what about something that's transitive and reflexive, not symmetric.?

Comment: @chris gave you one: $\leq$. Is it transitive? Yes, because $a\leq b\wedge b\leq c$ implies that $a\leq c$. Is it reflexive? Yes, because $a\leq a$ is true for each $a\in\mathbb R$. Is it symmetric? No, because we have $1\leq2$, but we have not $2\leq1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\leq %Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet$

Comment: does the one for neither of them work?

Comment: Sure! You might want to be more explicit with the "mostly" part, by producing particular examples. To prove that $\sim$ is not reflexive, observe that $0\not\sim0$, and so on.

Comment: kind of lost me there I should find examples where it works or doesn't work?

Comment: If someone else were to claim that $\sim$ is reflexive, they would be claiming that $x\sim x$ for ALL $x$. If you want to prove them wrong -- if you want to prove that $\sim$ is NOT reflexive, then you just have to prove the negation $x\not\sim x$ for ONE $x$. In your case, $0\not\sim 0$, since $0\neq0^2+1$.

Comment: how about something that's transitive and reflexive, not symmetric.

Comment: That's my answer: $\leq$ is transitive and reflexive, but not symmetric.